# ¿Como se interpreta la evaluación de la negación de un método bool en c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente metodo me gustaria saber como se interpreta

```
 if (!existe_producto(ListaProd, item1.codigo))
 {
     item1.Descripcion = item1.codigo + " - " + item1.Descripcion;
     ListaProdx.Add(item1);
 }

   private bool existe_producto(List<Ex_Producto> full_codigo, long codigo)
    {
        try
        {
            bool resp = false;
            foreach (var c in full_codigo)
            {
                if (c.codigox == codigo)
                {
                    resp = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return resp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Es decir cuando yo evaluo if(bool) es decir si mi variable es igual a true pero
cuando digo if(!bool) de un metodo que devuelve true o false como se lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente va a negar lo que devuelva `existe_producto()`, si este retorna un `true` entonces lo convierte a `false` eso sera lo que evalue el `if`

[! Operador (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/logical-negation-operator)

Comment: Leandro Tuttini si el metodo devuelve false entonces hace esto if(distinto(false))?

Comment: si el metodo devuelve false lo invierte a true. si te es dificil verlo puedes separar la funcionalidad en varias lineas:   bool result = existe_producto(ListaProd, item1.codigo);  if (!result) {...

Answer (score 1):

El operador "!" es un operador de **negación**, y lo que hace es convertir uno de los booleanos (`true` o `false`) en su respectivo contrario. En un lenguaje llano, vagamente podrías verlo como "Si x **no es** tal cosa, **entonces...**".

Por ejemplo, en tu caso:

```
if (!existe_producto(ListaProd, item1.codigo))
 {
     item1.Descripcion = item1.codigo + " - " + item1.Descripcion;
     ListaProdx.Add(item1);
 }
```

suponemos que el método "existe_producto()" devuelve verdadero `(true)` si efectivamente existe. Al agregar el operador de negación ("!") es como si dijeras: "**Si *no*** existe el producto, **entonces...**".

Si granularamos el código, un equivalente sería algo como:

```
if(existe_producto(ListaProd, item1.codigo) == false) //Es decir, no existe
{
    ... //tu código
}
```

Para más información, puedes consultar el enlace que dejó Leandro: [! Operador (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/logical-negation-operator)